# Can I use APC with Redis for PHP cache?

Tags: php, caching, yii, redis, apc

I'm trying to use cache to speed up my website.(PHP, highly dynamic like stackoverflow).

I was told that redis is so fast and great for a cache system, i believe stackoverflow uses redis as well. However, I'm wondering that can I/should I use APC with redis?

Because when i installed APC, it did not require my to change any of my codes, to support the reddis cache, i need to change a lot of stuff. So i'm very confused right now. Aren't they the same kind of cache system? Should I use both of them or they really do exactly the same thing?

Thanks so much!

Comment: APC is an __opcode cache__, that you can also use as a __data cache__ (if you write the code to use it that way); redis is a __data cache__ (which also requires you to change the code to use it). If you didn't need to change any code when you installed APC, then you're only using it as an __opcode cache__; redis will not replace that

Comment: And in answer to your question, `yes` they can be used together